# How to poll kafka for the messages that has timestamp less than 30 seconds?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I want to poll only the records that have produced less than 30 seconds. Is there any way in the Kafka polling that I can consume only the messages that are produced only less than 30 seconds?

Any suggestions or advice will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what will happen to those messages that were not processed due to fully occupied consumers?

Comment: Basically I want to drop those messages ( > 30 seconds) during the poll.

Comment: another way is to set lifespan of the messages, if it's there for more than 30 secs, dispose

Answer (score 2):

You could use the offsetsForTimes method which returns you offset whose timestamp is greater or equal to the give timestamp. More information on the official doc here :

https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#offsetsForTimes(java.util.Map)

After getting the offset you can seek using it and starting to read from there.

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetAndTimestamp